# Anti de Sitter Motion without matter

Tags: general-relativity, anti-de-sitter-spacetime

I've read that a non zero cosmological constant can lead to "motion without matter" in vacuum spacetimes such as AdS.

Initially I didn't understand what the significance of this statement was since I thought Schwarzschild (also vacuum) induces motion on any test particles but it has been pointed out to me that Schwarzschild has a non-zero ADM mass i.e. it doesn't have any matter in the sense that all the matter is at the singularity.

So then it is clear that AdS is special if there is motion without matter i.e. the motion is coming purely from the cosmological constant. However, in this paper (http://arxiv.org/pdf/hep-th/9902121.pdf) they modify the ADM prescription for AdS spaces and fin that there is still a notion of mass or vacuum energy here - makes sense as we have a timelike Killing vector. But if there is a vacuum energy in AdS then there is "matter" and so surely the statement of AdS having "motion without matter" is wrong, no?

Comment: That depends on what exactly you mean by "motion without matter", so it's just word games, since "motion without matter" is not a technical term in physics.

Comment: @ACuriousMind I guess so. But if there is a vacuum energy for AdS, why is it not lumped into the $T_{\mu \nu}$ term? This is some kind of Casimir energy and is treated differently to regular matter?